¿Como sacar los subtotales y el total de una misma tabla en MySQL?
Buen día, tengo el siguiente inconveniente:
Estoy realizando una consulta para extraer los subtotales y el total de una tabla de ventas, la tabla es la siguiente:

Y quiero sacar la suma de los subtotales de cada grupo y agruparlos por cada número de venta, dando un resultado similar a este:
venta | IVA2 | IVA16 | EXCENTO | TOTAL
  1   | 120  | 900   | 80      |  1100
  2   |  60  |  0    |  0      |  60

La verdad mi código es muy austero y solo puedo hacerlo con el grupo IVA12:
SELECT SUM(subTotal) FROM d23 WHERE grupo = "IVA2"
GROUP BY numeroVenta

Quería combinar las sumas de cada subtotal, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.
Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda que me brinden.

Tenes que transponer la tabla, que es transponer una tabla? reorganizarla para convertir las columnas en filas y las filas en columnas... Podes hacer esto con la función CASE y la función de agregación SUM(), en combinación con GROUP BY (agrupamos por numero de venta), nos ayudamos de COALESCE para que, si un registro contiene un valor null, este se convierta a 0:
SELECT 
    numeroVenta,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Grupo = 'IVA2' THEN Subtotal END), 0) as IVA2,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Grupo = 'IVA16' THEN Subtotal END), 0) as IVA16,
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN Grupo = 'EXCENTO' THEN Subtotal END), 0) as EXCENTO,
    SUM(subtotal) as TOTAL
FROM SALES
GROUP BY numeroVenta

Tenes mas información sobre la transposición de tablas aqui
Un saludo.

La verdad te agradezco infinitamente tu respuesta, me has dado exactamente el resultado que he estado buscando, la mayoría de la sintaxis de la consulta no la entiendo como por ejemplo el CASE y no conocía lo que es COALESCE así que también me has enseñado algo nuevo, la verdad me capacitaré más en SQL ya que soy un completo neófito, de nuevo, muchísimas gracias por haberme ayudado con mi problema, te deseo mucho éxito compañero.

El CASE es similar a los if/else de un lenguaje de programación corriente, cada case es como decir if(Grupo === 'IVA2') { return Subtotal } y asi con todos los grupos, de todas maneras en el link tenes toda la información.

Una duda: ¿Ese COALESCE no debería ir dentro del SUM y no fuera? Ten en cuenta que, todo lo que operes con NULL, se irá a NULL.

@DavidJP es una buena pregunta, en MySQL la funcion SUM() ignora los valores null, asi que el COALESCE es mas que nada para que si cierta venta no tiene algún tipo de impuesto (IVA2 o IVA16 etc), este sea mostrado como 0 en lugar de NULL.

Y en el caso absurdo de que los subtotales de una venta pudiesen ser todos null, estos se ignoran y la funcion SUM devuelve null, que se convierte a 0
